# Interpolating Data Points in a Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I'm studying Functional data analysis. But Length of each data are different.
There are 50 observation. And these observation have 150~200 length.
So I use this method but I want to know higher level method.
This is my method.
"Create a function that connects two points in a straight line and add points using the straight line function."
My method is not perfect. there are NA in the result of y value.
I think It is possible to use curve like spline instead straight line for add data point.
Or could you help me with another genius way? I will really appreciate.

```
# This is just example. This is temperature data. Original data have 310~370 lengths.
ex[[1]] <- c(12.2, 12.1, 12.1, 12.0, 11.9, 11.8, 11.8, 11.9, 11.8, 11.9, 12.0, 11.9)
ex[[2]] <- c(12.3, 13.4, 13.3, 13.4, 13.3, 13.4, 13.2, 13.4, 13.5, 13.5)
ex[[3]] <- c(12.8, 12.8, 12.7, 12.7, 12.9, 12.5, 12.7, 12.6, 12.7, 13.0, 12.8, 12.7, 12.9, 12.0)

lengths(ex)
## V1 V2 V3 
## 12 10 14

RoundMidf <- function(tv, xv){ # tv : targe vector of list,  xv : reference vector
  x <- c(1:length(xv))*length(tv)/length(xv) # 
  x1 <- ifelse(x < 1, ceiling(x), floor(x))
  x2 <- ceiling(x)
  y1 <- tv[x1]
  y2 <- tv[x2]
  a <- (y1-y2)/(x1-x2) # a of y=ax+b
  b <- y1-a*x1 # b of y=ax+b
  y <- a*x+b # y of y=ax+b
  y[length(xv)] <- tv[length(tv)] # Last point doesn't have next point
  return(y)
}

newex <- as.list(NA)
newex[[1]] <- RoundMidf(ex[[1]], ex[[3]])
newex[[2]] <- RoundMidf(ex[[2]], ex[[3]])
newex[[3]] <- ex[[3]] # reference

# Compare the data lengths before and after
DT <- data.frame(lengths(ex),lengths(newex)); names(DT) <- c("Old", "New"); DT
##    Old New
## V1  12  14
## V2  10  14
## V3  14  14
```

Comment: You mint want to check out the `zoo` package if you are interested in interpolating NA values in time series. In particular, the `zoo::na.approx()` function that allows for both linear and cubic spline interpolation.

Comment: Thank you @MattSummersgill It really help full.